# Como pegar somente hora de timestamp?

Tags: firebird, timestamp

Tenho uma coluna *timestamp* na minha tabela e preciso pegar somente a hora desses valores.

Exemplo de como está cadastrado: **30.12.1899 17:03**

Exemplo de como eu preciso exibir através de select: **17:00**

Eu consegui desse jeito:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN Char_length(Extract(hour FROM coluna)) <= 1 THEN '0' ||  Extract( hour FROM coluna )  || ':00' 
    ELSE Extract(hour FROM coluna) || ':00' 
  end AS "DATA"
FROM   tabela
```

Tem um jeito mais fácil de eu conseguir chegar no mesmo resultado?

**OBS: Preciso somente da hora com duas casas decimais, os minutos serão fixos, ou seja, sempre será 00.**

Comment: Cara, não entendo da linguagem em questão, mas analisando programaticamente, acho que o código já direto e fácil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desse modo você extrai a Hora Minuto e Segundo do Campo `date` e `timestamp` do Firebird veja [Aqui](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/InterBase/XE7/en/Extracting_Date_and_Time_Information) o Conteudo Completo sobre extrair data e Hora do campo `timestamp`

```
SELECT EXTRACT (HOUR FROM tabela.Campo) ||
':' || EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM tabela.Campo) ||
':' || EXTRACT (SECOND FROM tabela.Campo) FROM tabela
```